# How to run an activty in background while executing an another activity in foreground android

Tags: android, android-intent, service, android-activity

I'm beginner to android application, In my application, i want to run one activity in backgronud(application setting page) while executing another activity. Anyone please help me with example code.. Thanks in advance

Comment: Activity is not a background task. You can have service in background or thread. What you want to achieve?

Comment: Maybe an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) is a better option.